# Dynamics Web API BATCH POST vs PATCH (remove navigation property value)

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am attempting to [Disassociate a reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/associate-disassociate-entities-using-web-api#disassociate-table-rows-on-update) a contact reference to a single-valued navigation property by setting the value to null.

This works when I call the web api directly:

```
PATCH https://mydynamics.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/contacts(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)
{ "firstname": "John",
"lastname":"Doe",
"lookup1@odata.bind": null,
"lookup2@odata.bind": null,
"lookup3@odata.bind": null
}
//[...other data omitted for brevity...]
```

So these lookup fields, lookup 1,2, and 3 would be reset to null (The association is removed).

We run a synchronization program that calls these operations in a batch and when this runs -- using the same payload -- the lookup fields fail to reset (although if I modified firstname or lastname - those fields would update). This is a POST batch call containing just the single PATCH operation in this case but it normally contains multiple operations.
All documentation I can find states that PATCH with multiple operation should be a POST call but it didn't reset my lookups.

If I change the POST batch to a PATCH batch...then it works as expected and all fields are updated correctly including the lookups!

Why the difference between BATCH POST vs PATCH?!

- Is is a bug in the API?
- Is it because I only had a single operation
  in the batch? Would it work for multiple requests? (I didnt try).
- Does using PATCH instead of POST have any negative affect on either a
  single operation or multiple operations?  Suppose a DELETE operation
  was also in the batch for something? [Microsoft says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/execute-batch-operations-using-web-api#batch-requests) "Use a POST
  request to submit a batch operation that contains multiple requests.
  A batch request can include GET requests and change sets."
- Why is the
  documentation lacking on this topic?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Read your question while searching for related CRM WEB API challenges.
The response may be a bit overdue but here's what I think applies to your case:

- POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE are HTTP request types.
- When using PATCH on MS CRM you can only edit a single record.
- When you want to perform multiple operations at once you use a POST request to post a whole batch of different requests. This can include multiple PATCH requests.

How to POST a batch is described quite okay here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/execute-batch-operations-using-web-api

Comment: Hmm... yes it is described, though it is not working:-)